# How can I restore the original ringtones and sounds?

Tags: nexus-one, audio, restore, ringtone

Without really thinking, I used the "clear data" command on the Media Storage app, which deleted all the stock ringtones and notification sounds from my Nexus One. How can I get them back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"all the stock ringtones and notification sounds" cannot be deleted without root. What happened here is, you've "dropped the index": the "Media Storage" app is what scans your media files from all over the device (including those on SD card), and maintains an "index" in form of a database. This is done for faster access, so apps using your media files have not all to scan the entire device themselves, but use a "cheaper and faster" call to that database instead.

What your "clear data" on this app did was not removing the media files themselves, but emptying that database – so apps relying on it won't see the files anymore. This gets fixed the next time the [media-scanner](/questions/tagged/media-scanner) runs. If you don't want to wait for that, the easiest way to force the media scanner to run is rebooting the device, as it always runs on "boot completed".

See also:

- our [media-scanner tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/media-scanner/info)
- [most frequented questions using the `media-scanner` tag](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/media-scanner?sort=frequent)

Comment: It really helped after forcing media storage App.

Answer (score 4):

If you are rooted, you can push [this collection of media files](http://www.megaupload.com/?d=Y9GK1M3U) to /system/media/

Without root, android should still locate the files if you place them in a folder on your SD card called "media" and retain the rest of the file structure from the zip.

Answer (score 0):

I did a restart of my phone and everything was back to normal. Hope this helps someone.

I have been constantly facing no-enough-space-remaining errors, which would block certain services and this had probably did some messing up with my ringtone settings. After restart, I was able to find my ringtones back where it should have been.

Comment: Considering the lack of details I suggest you make this a comment since it is a one liner low quality answer right now (flagged as VLQ already).

Comment: This answer is an ample answer. Be it a one line or one word. I had my ringtone lost since couple of weeks. If you don't agree, downvote at your will, but be reasonable :)

Comment: @linuxeasy "reasonable" is exactly the keyword here: could you [edit] your answer and include the reason this should work for? Some more background would already make it justifyable.